# React Native IOS Universal link is open in safari instead of App

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

I am using react native IOS deeplinking and App is not open through the link after completing deepliking setup.

I have already added the apple-app-site-association file to the web server but it's not working.

Here is my apple-app-site-association file code:-

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "<TeamID>.<BundleID>”,
      "paths": ["*"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added it to the associated domains in your app?

Comment: Yes I'have already added but it's not working. Is there any kind of solution you've , so kindly help me. My website URL is something like this : "http://www.myapp.com/contract/id"